# Using garbanzo flour instead of canned garbanzo beans

Tags: substitutions, flour, beans, chickpeas

If I wanted to substitute chickpea flour for a can of garbanzo beans in a recipe, how would I prepare the flour? should I mix a amount of water with it and cook it? and if so how much water?

Here's the recipe in question, [Zero Sp Bananabonzo Bread](https://www.copymethat.com/r/TYtC3LJ/zero-sp-bananabonzo-bread/).

Ingredients:

- 1 can drained garbanzo beans
- 3 very ripe soft bananas
- 5 eggs
- 1 1/2 tsp baking powder
- 1 tsp cinnamon
- 1 tsp vanilla
- 1/2 tsp pumpkin pie spice
- 1/2 tsp salt
- 2 packets of Trivia (stevia)

Comment: Hey, Lia, people can help you better if they know what recipe you're trying to make with this substitution.

Comment: https://www.copymethat.com/r/TYtC3LJ/zero-sp-bananabonzo-bread/

Answer (score 4):

For this specific recipe, you may be able to get away with this substitution, since what you're making is a bread, but also because it's a bread there's less room for error than in many dishes. Rather than try to substitute in this specific recipe, I'd look for another recipe for banana bread made with garbanzo bean flour - a cursory google found many - and alter sweeteners and spices as needed or desired to get closer to this one.  (Most artificial sweeteners have established, standardized subsitutions for sugar, so that's going to be an easier change than using chickpea flour in place of canned garbanzos.)

Answer (score 0):

Garbanzo, afaik, is also known as chickpeas.

Chickpea flour is simply ground dried chickpeas. You should be able to substitute chickpea flour, 1:1 with dried chickpeas.

When cooked (and canned) chickpeas would be soaking water, almost 1 to 1.5 times their dry weight. So Let's say 1.25 times. So... You should be able to substitute chickpea flour, 1:2.25 with cooked chickpeas

Comment: If you substitue cooked beans though, you'll hav to find a way of reducing the liquid elsewhere in the recipe.  For some recipes that wouldn't even be possible (I've made chapattis using chickpea flour, for example)

Comment: If it calls for 1 can of chickpeas blended how much chickpea flour and water should I use? and will I have to cook it first and then add it to my receipt, or can I just add the flour and water to it?

Comment: @ChrisH The substitution in this case is the other way. The recipe calls for beans, so water will need to be added.

Comment: @Catija, true. Still the answer, IMO, should address the adjustment in the water.